# Tascam DR-100 carry case: PortaBrace AR-100, Petrol PS615 or a camera case?

Tags: petrol, portable-recorder, cases

Hi guys,

Just wondering what Tascam DR-100 / DR-100MkII users are using for a carry case? I'm looking at the [PortaBrace AR-100](http://www.portabrace.com/products/audio/recorders/733-audio-recorder-case-for-tascam-dr100mkii) or the [Petrol Bags PS615](http://www.petrolbags.com/product/PS615), or finding a suitable camera case as people have suggested in other threads on here.

The AR-100 is fairly expensive for what it is, but it does have the strap clips at the bottom, so when you have it on the strap it's "upside-down"; the right way up for the user. The PS615 looks a little nicer and is a little cheaper, but the clips are on the top, meaning it'd be upside-down for the user...

Anyone have any suggestion or experience with either? Are the controls easy to access through the plastic cover? The main problem I can see at the moment is trying to use the dial control on the front of the DR-100 through the plastic, but that's always going to be the case with such a design!

Thanks in advance!